# Receber dados de Json externo e exibir seu conteúdo em laço como array usando PHP

Tags: php

A url externa tem um estrutura de dados que recebo em meu código e ela está sendo recebida como uma string `JSON`, tentei decodificá-la mas não obtive nenhum resultado.

http://publisher.windi.com.br/manager/estoquejson/?hash=8d37ddfa64d1e0a2d9cb887c2ed86619&l=8910809

**Espero receber a string `JSON` e convertê-la no formato abaixo:**

```
array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

**Meu PHP**

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
$urlPath = "http://publisher.windi.com.br/manager/estoquejson/?hash=8d37ddfa64d1e0a2d9cb887c2ed86619&l=8910809";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPath);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Imprimo
echo $result;
// Aqui sai como string, tentei converter a estrutura para array mas sem sucesso.
```

> // { "veiculos": [ { "id": 164999, "destaque": 0, "anoFabricacao":
>   2011, "anoModelo": 2012, "km": 86000, "portas": 4, "valorVenda":
>   29990.0, "dataEntradaEstoque": "Apr 27, 2019 12:00:00 PM",  ................

Sabendo que:

> PHP> = 5.2.0 apresenta uma função, json_decode, que decodifica uma
>   sequência JSON em uma variável PHP. Por padrão, ele retorna um objeto.
>   O segundo parâmetro aceita um booleano que, quando definido como true,
>   diz para ele retornar os objetos como matrizes associativas. Você pode
>   aprender mais sobre a função json_decode na documentação do PHP.

A saída para a alteração que fiz não resulta em nada.

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
$urlPath = "http://publisher.windi.com.br/manager/estoquejson/?hash=8d37ddfa64d1e0a2d9cb887c2ed86619&l=8910809";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPath);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Decodifiquei a string `JSON` esperando algo, mas a exibição foi em branco.
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($obj);

// Ou com var_dump(); retornou NULL
var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão, o json_decode já é true, por isso não há necessidade de setá-lo, a menos que você queira receber isso em array, daí seta para false. Experimente converter o charset antes de converter para o decode de json:

```
$rtn = json_decode(utf8_encode($result))
print_r($rtn);
```

Eu fiz o seguinte e deu certo:

```
function getExternalUrl($url_metodo, $info = false)
{

    try {
        $mime_type = null;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_metodo);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        list($mime, $charset) = explode(';', curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
        $saida = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $mime = null;
        $charset = null;
        $saida = file_get_contents($url_metodo);
    }
    if ($info) {
        return array('file' => $saida, 'mime' => $mime, 'charset' => $charset);
    } else {
        return $saida;
    }
}

$obj = getExternalUrl('http://publisher.windi.com.br/manager/estoquejson/?hash=8d37ddfa64d1e0a2d9cb887c2ed86619&l=8910809');

print_r(json_decode(utf8_encode($obj)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem dois erros muito comuns em strings formatadas em JSON, a primeira é em relação ao charset já que a função `json_decode` suporta apenas UTF-8; a segunda pode ser erro de formatação da string, a estrura em si, talvez falte uma chave `{}`, uma aspa `"` ou qualquer outro caracter de controle.

Por isso é sempre bom usar o tratamento de erros que já vem por padrão no PHP.

Você pode descobrir exatamente o que está acontecendo com uma pequena modificação no código:

```php
<?php

// ...

$obj = json_decode($result, true);

if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
}
```

E a partir daí tomar as providências necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda da resposta do @Diego Martins consegui resolver o problema verificando o erro que impedia a conversão de string JSON para os objetos como matrizes associativas e segue abaixo a solução.

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$urlPath = "http://publisher.windi.com.br/manager/estoquejson/?hash=8d37ddfa64d1e0a2d9cb887c2ed86619&l=8910809";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPath);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = utf8_encode($result);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);

if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
}

if(is_array($obj)) {
    echo "<p>É array</p>";
} else {
    echo "<pre>Não é array</pre>";
}

// Retornou "É array"

echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
echo "</pre>";

// Retornou a estrutura de array
```

Comment: Mantive o IF e o PRINT_R somente para efeitos de informação, assim como também o json_last_error por ser ambiente de desenvolvimento, com as alterações de encode posso continuar o que tenho para fazer.